# What is the maximum voltage that can be applied across the whole network?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, voltage

Two resistors $3.0 \space k\Omega$ and $2.2\space k\Omega$ resistor are connected in parallel; this combination is connected in series with a $1.3\space k\Omega$ resistor. If each resistor is rated at $13W$ (maximum without overheating), what is the maximum voltage that can be applied across the whole network?

I've been stuck on this homework problem for a long time. First, I found the total resistance to be $2.569\space k\omega$.

Then I used

$$
\begin{align}
P &= i^2 R\\
1/3 &= i^2 (2.569x10^3)\\ 
i & = 0.0114
\end{align}
$$

Finally, I used

$$
\begin{align}
V&=IR\\ 
V&=0.0114(2.569x10^3)\\ 
V&= 29.26V\\
\end{align}
$$

This is not the right answer. Could you please help me where I went wrong?

Comment: First, instead of looking at the network as a whole, you have to remember that the circuit is only as strong as its weakest link.

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram. All circuit questions should have a complete, annotated diagram with every resistance and voltage source labeled with the same variable names as used in the text of the question. Without this, circuit questions are very hard to understand and answer well.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically 1/3 of the way there. The key is that you need to consider each element individually.

A general procedure:

1. Find the total resistance
2. For a given voltage, find the total current passing through the system
3. For a given total current, find the individual current flowing through each resistor
4. For a given individual current, find the power dissipated by that element
5. One of the elements will have the most power dissipated per unit total current. This is your limiting resistor.
6. Extrapolate to find the voltage

I will do one of the resistors as an example. 
Call the resistors in parallel $R_{p1}$ and $R_{p2}$. Call the resistor in series $R_{s1}$.

$R_{tot} = R_{s1} + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{p1}}+\frac{1}{R_{p2}}}$

$I_{tot} = \frac{V_{tot}}{R_{tot}}$

$I_{s1} = I_{tot}$

$P_{s1} = I_{s1}^2 * R_{s1} = \frac{V_{tot}^2 * R_{s1}}{\bigg(R_{s1} + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{p1}}+\frac{1}{R_{p2}}}\bigg)^2}$

Now, you have the total allowable voltage **IF** the series resistor is the limiting factor. Do the same thing for the two resistors in series, solve for the total voltage, and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation assumes that the **total** power dissipated in the circuit is 13W. The question says the maximum power dissipated **in each resistor** is 13W.

---

Let $R_1$ be the series resistor and $R_2$, $R_3$ the parallel resistors. Using your formula for power $P=I^2R$ you can calculate the maximum currents $I_1^*$, $I_2^*$ and $I_3^*$ which can be allowed through each resistor.

The same current $I_1$ flows through the series and parallel combinations. If $I_1^*$ is the smallest current, then the currents through the parallel resistors are guaranteed to be smaller than their maximums. You have already calculated the total resistance $R_T$, so you can calculate the maximum voltage across the network of resistors straight away, using $V=I_1^*R_T$.

Otherwise, look at the currents through the parallel resistors. Suppose current $I_2^*$ flows through $R_2$. Then the current through $R_3$ will be $I_3=(R_2/R_3)I_2^*$ because the voltages across $R_2$ and $R_3$ are the same ($I_2^*R_2=I_3R_3$).

Now if $I_3 > I_3^*$ then putting $I_2^*$ through $R_2$ causes $R_3$ to overload. So in this case $I_3^*$ is the limiting current. Then you can calculate $I_2=(R_3/R_2)I_3^*$ and find the total current in the circuit $I_1=I_2+I_3^*$. Finally calculate maximum voltage $V=I_1R_T$.

On the other hand if $I_3 \le I_3^*$ then putting $I_2^*$ through $R_2$ **does not** cause $R_3$ to overload. In this case $I_2^*$ is the limiting current. Then you can calculate the total current in the circuit $I_1=I_2^*+I_3$ and the maximum voltage $V=I_1R_T$.